# How to write Matrix with multiple data types python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I am trying to implement a matrix (in Python 3.7), what would be the best way  if the matrix has multiple data types inside of it? For example, I have a text file with the following contents:

```
~ A B C  
A 0 1 2  
B 2 2 2  
C 3 1 0
```

Including the hyphen, integers and string values. I have considered a few different options:
1) Using Numpy structured arrays
2) Using standard python via the following method:

```
matrix = open('matrix1.txt').read()  
matrix = [item.split() for item in matrix.split('\n')]
```

The structured arrays didn't seem very practical/easy to use, and the second method didn't seem as clear when output as numpy's general zeros array etc, where they are output in an easy to read fashion.

TLDR; What is the python method of implementing a multi-variable matrix which can be read easily by the user?

Comment: The example you provided makes me think you just need to keep your row and column names somewhere close to your regular integer matrix and write a custom parser/serializer for this combined structure.

Comment: Yeah, actually putting the row/column labels and the tilde (not a hyphen) in the matrix itself seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Are you going to do any calculations with the numbers?  If not, you could just make a string dtype array.  Even then, you could do the calculations on `arr[1:, 1:].astype(int)`.

Comment: If you are mainly concerned with display, why not just leave it in the text form that's on the file?  The text could also be reconstructed from the list of lists that your code produces - with `join`.

Comment: Maybe pandas is a better option for you? using `pandas.read_csv('matrix1.txt')` It does pretty good job of parsing different data types.